# How to translate add_contextual_help to get_current_screen()->add_help_tab()

Tags: contextual-help

I followed this tutorial: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-settings-api-part-1-create-a-theme-options-page/

There is a deprecated tag

```
add_contextual_help
```

It says to use this instead

```
get_current_screen()->add_help_tab()
```

However, I don't understand how to translate add_contextual_help to get_current_screen()->add_help_tab()

This is the block of code that uses add_contextual_help

```
/**
 * The Admin menu page
 */
function wptuts_add_menu(){

$settings_output        = wptuts_get_settings();
// collect our contextual help text
$wptuts_contextual_help = $settings_output['wptuts_contextual_help'];

// Display Settings Page link under the "Appearance" Admin Menu
// add_theme_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function);
$wptuts_settings_page = add_theme_page(__('Wptuts Options'), __('Wptuts Options','wptuts_textdomain'), 'manage_options', WPTUTS_PAGE_BASENAME, 'wptuts_settings_page_fn');
    // contextual help
    if ($wptuts_settings_page) {
        add_contextual_help( $wptuts_settings_page, $wptuts_contextual_help );
    }
    // css & js
    add_action( 'load-'. $wptuts_settings_page, 'wptuts_settings_scripts' );    
}
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry only have time to offer a quick fix....

See where you can go from here..

```
/**
 * The Admin menu page
 */
function wptuts_add_menu(){

    // Display Settings Page link under the "Appearance" Admin Menu
    // add_theme_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function);
    $wptuts_settings_page = add_theme_page(__('Wptuts Options'), __('Wptuts Options','wptuts_textdomain'), 'manage_options', WPTUTS_PAGE_BASENAME, 'wptuts_settings_page_fn');

    // css & js
    add_action( 'load-'. $wptuts_settings_page, 'wptuts_settings_scripts' );
    add_action( 'load-'. $wptuts_settings_page, 'wptuts_add_help' );
}
function wptuts_add_help() {

    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if( !method_exists( $screen, 'add_help_tab' ) )
        return;

    $settings_output        = wptuts_get_settings();

    // collect our contextual help text
    $wptuts_contextual_help = $settings_output['wptuts_contextual_help'];

    $sidebar = '<ul>
        <li><a href="http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/YOUR_PLUGIN/faq/">' . __( 'FAQ', 'your_text_domain' ) . '</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/YOUR_PLUGIN/other_notes/">' . __( 'Other notes', 'your_text_domain' ) . '</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/YOUR_PLUGIN/changelog/">' . __( 'Change Log', 'your_text_domain' ) . '</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/YOUR_PLUGIN#topic">' . __( 'Support', 'your_text_domain' ) . '</a></li>
    </ul>';


    $screen->add_help_tab( array( 'title' => __( 'Title One', 'your_text_domain' ), 'id' => 'id1', 'content' => 'text example'));
    $screen->add_help_tab( array( 'title' => __( 'Title Two', 'your_text_domain' ), 'id' => 'id2',    'content' => 'text example'));
    $screen->add_help_tab( array( 'title' => __( 'Title Three', 'your_text_domain' ), 'id' => 'id3', 'content' => 'text example'));
    $screen->set_help_sidebar( $sidebar );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty easy. You're already adding your options page using add_theme_page. So add something like this:

```
add_action( 'load-'. $wptuts_settings_page, 'mytheme_contextual_help' );
```

Now, make a function to add your contextual help tabs, like so:

```
function mytheme_contextual_help() {
   $screen = get_current_screen();
   $screen->add_help_tab( array(
      'id'      => 'help-tab-1',
      'title'   => 'Title of the first Help Tab',
      'content' => '<p>HTML for this help tab</p>',
   ));

   $screen->add_help_tab( array(
      'id'      => 'help-tab-2',
      'title'   => 'Title of the second Help Tab',
      'content' => '<p>HTML for this help tab</p>',
   ));

}
```

And so forth.

You can also call set_help_sidebar in this function to add a right hand sidebar for links and similar.

More info:

http://ottopress.com/2011/new-in-wordpress-3-3-more-useful-help-screens/

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Screen/add_help_tab

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Screen/set_help_sidebar